# Not Able to receive Request Access Token from Connected Apps

Tags: apex, connected-apps, callback

I tried this **Connected App** setting but inside my codes I'm receiving null value for my **Request Access Token** in the codes.

***Can someone help me check whats the problem?***

---

*I'm Testing the code using the Developer Console*

**Developer Console Code**

`testFBInt s = new testFBInt();
 s.Execute();`

---

**The place where I'm taking my Connected App *Consumer ID* and *Consumer Secret***

[image]

> The Black Lines are where I take my Values from

---

**Connected App OAuth Setting**

[image: Connected App OAuth Setting]

**Update list of Callback URL I have tested**

- https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
- https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
- https://login.salesforce.com/service
- http://localhost/test/start.php

---

**Code**

```
global class testFBInt {

global void Execute(){

String sessionId = requestAccessToken();

System.Debug('@sesionid' + sessionId);
exInt(sessionId);
}

public String requestAccessToken() {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(tokenEndpoint);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(buildHttpQuery(new Map<String, String> {
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'username' =>  username,
        'password' => password,
        'client_id' => consumer_id,
        'client_secret' => consumer_secret
    }));

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);

    Map<String, Object> m =
        (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resp.getBody());

    return (String) m.get('access_token');
}

static String buildHttpQuery(Map<String, String> queryParams) {
    if (queryParams.isEmpty()) {
        return '';
    }

    String[] params = new String[] {};
    for (String k : queryParams.keySet()) {
        String v = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(queryParams.get(k), 'UTF-8');

        params.add(String.format('{0}={1}', new String[] { k, v }));
    }

    return String.join(params, '&');
}


 @future(callout=true)
 public static void exInt(string sessionId) {




String dashboardImageURL = 'https://ap4.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ChartServer?rsid=....';

String base64Data;
httprequest req = new httprequest();
req.setEndpoint(dashboardImageURL);
req.setmethod('GET');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + sessionId);
http http = new http();
httpresponse res = http.send(req);
Blob image = res.getBodyAsBlob();
base64Data =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(image);


Document docatt = new Document();
docatt.Name = 'Chart 1.jpg';
docatt.Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data);
docatt.FOLDERID = '00l6F035601pqGi'; //Your folder id
docatt.IsPublic = true;

insert docatt;

System.Debug('@@ doc ' + docatt);
```

---

**Debug Logs**
[image]

Comment: In your posted code are the credentials placeholders or are you really using username and password. You are getting invalid client id in your logs

Comment: they are the credentials placeholders that I hard code into the program

Comment: Check your client id. Log is saying it is invalid. Your code also does not handle the various possible response codes. You are getting a status code 400. The debug is null because of the invalid credentials.

Comment: I copy & paste the full client id from the connected app and the full client secret from the app

Comment: Working code maybe will help https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/85664/oauth-implementation/85679#85679

Comment: Could be because of the CallBack URL? I don't know what Callback URL to use so I been taking it from this two places. [link 1](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000DEvBIAW) [link 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20559/what-is-the-use-of-setting-oauth-callback-url-as-https-login-salesforce-com-se)

Comment: I believe if the callback URL does not match it will tell you. The logs say the client id is invalid. Use the code in the example I gave with your values. If it does not work you know you are using incorrect values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57452/discussion-between-luke-au-and-eric).

Comment: @Eric shall we continue this in Chat I got some questions about it to ask you